# HTML DOM - element.appendChild() doesn't behave as I expect it to

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom, appendchild

link to code (js and css can be found through the page source): https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16952797/webdev/uppg1/kontakt.html
alt link: http://jsfiddle.net/DdQhk/ (although jsfiddle does not render the page properly)

relevant lines of code (function createFormBug() - line 31 to 66 in kontakt.js)
code:

```
function createFormBug() {
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    var fieldset = document.createElement("fieldset");
    var legend = document.createElement("legend");
    var labelFunction = document.createElement("label");
    var labelInterface = document.createElement("label");
    var labelComment = document.createElement("label");
    var radioFunction = document.createElement("input");
    radioFunction.type = "radio";
    var radioInterface = document.createElement("input");
    radioInterface.type = "radio";
    var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
    var buttonSubmit = document.createElement("input");
    radioInterface.type = "submit";

    form.id = "formBug";

    legend.textContent = "Bugg";

    document.getElementById("divForm").appendChild(form);

    form.appendChild(fieldset);
    fieldset.appendChild(legend);
    fieldset.appendChild(labelFunction);
    fieldset.appendChild(radioFunction);
    fieldset.appendChild(labelInterface);
    fieldset.appendChild(radioInterface);
    fieldset.appendChild(labelComment);
    fieldset.appendChild(textarea);
    fieldset.appendChild(buttonSubmit);





}
```

context: I'm trying to create a form dynamically by using js, unfortunately some elements aren't being appended for some reason.

partial output of generated html when run on Chrome (relevant section):

```
<div id="divForm">
    <form id="formBug">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Bugg</legend>
            <label></label>
            <input type="radio">
            <label></label>
            <input type="submit">
            <label></label>
            <textarea></textarea>
            <input>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Which elements aren't being appended? The only obvious mistake you have is `radioInterface.type = "submit";` You presumably mean `buttonSubmit.type = "submit";`

Comment: thanks for that one, fixed it.. I'll check if I'm missing any other elements.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it and edited the textContent attribute of the labels to make them visible, would you like to write an answer so I can mark it as approved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is working pretty much as you might expect it to.  The only obvious mistake is that you are setting `radioInterface.type = "submit";` where you presumably mean `buttonSubmit.type = "submit";`.

It should be apparent that this works fine if you actually put some content in to make elements like `label` actually visible...

Something like this, perhaps?

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
var fieldset = document.createElement("fieldset");
var legend = document.createElement("legend");

var labelFunction = document.createElement("label");
labelFunction.textContent = 'Function'; // <-- added
var labelInterface = document.createElement("label");
labelInterface.textContent = 'Interface'; // <-- added
var labelComment = document.createElement("label");
labelComment.textContent = 'Comment'; // <-- added

var radioFunction = document.createElement("input");
radioFunction.type = "radio";
var radioInterface = document.createElement("input");
radioInterface.type = "radio";

var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");

var buttonSubmit = document.createElement("input");
buttonSubmit.type = "submit"; // <-- corrected
```

I believe your code to actually add them to the document should be working fine.